# How Can I Can to change color on rows When equal quantity

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, spring-boot

| code | pre_qty | total_qty | col_input |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| book | 5 | 2 | color_blue |
| pen | 3 | 3 | color_red |
| pencil | 10 | 3 | color_blue |

-----this is my JS to change Back Color ----------------

```
        for (var obj of myDataCheck) {

                var quantity_rep = obj.quantity_rep;
                var quantity_total = obj.quantity_total;

                
                if (quantity_rep == quantity_total) {
                $(".input_out").css({
                    'background-color': '#8bc34a',
                })

                
            } else {

                $(".input_out").css({
                    'background-color': '#ffffff',
                })

                
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your array, I created an `HTML` table, And I added a `JS` function to manage what you want, I loop through each `tr` element, and For each `tr` element, I get the `td` elements with the classes `quantity_rep` and `quantity_total`, and extract their values. I convert these values to integers using the parseInt function, Then I compare their values if they are equal I set the background to `#8bc34a` else white:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#myDataCheck tbody tr').each(function() {
    var quantityRep = parseInt($(this).find('.quantity_rep').text());
    var quantityTotal = parseInt($(this).find('.quantity_total').text());
    if(quantityRep === quantityTotal) {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#8bc34a');
    } else {
      $(this).css('background-color', '#ffffff');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myDataCheck">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Code</th>
      <th>Quantity Rep</th>
      <th>Quantity Total</th>
      <th>Color Input</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="input_out0">
      <td class="code">book</td>
      <td class="quantity_rep">5</td>
      <td class="quantity_total">2</td>
      <td class="col_input">color_blue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="input_out1">
      <td class="code">pen</td>
      <td class="quantity_rep">3</td>
      <td class="quantity_total">3</td>
      <td class="col_input">color_red</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="input_out2">
      <td class="code">pencil</td>
      <td class="quantity_rep">10</td>
      <td class="quantity_total">3</td>
      <td class="col_input">color_blue</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
<table>
```

Comment: Thank Somuch amel for this help of my life

Comment: Anytime, glad to hear that helped you